# How to remove all rows which are higher than the index of a specific row in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to remove all rows above a row with a specific value in a column. If this specific value exists multiple times, the last match defines the removal. The dataframe looks as follows:

```
df =

      A             B          C         
0     Item1         20         5   
1     Item2         84         0  
2     Item3         93         1 
3     Item4         50         0
4     Item5         40         3
5     Item6          1         12
```

First I identify all rows with value "0" in Column C. I take the last one. Then I try to remove all rows above including the matched one.

```
c_zero_rows = df[ df["C"] == 0 ] # get all rows with value "0" in C
last_c_zero_row = c_zero_rows.tail(1) # get last of this rows

remaining_rows = df [ df.index > last_c_zero_row.index] # remove all rows above
```

My desired result should look like this:

```
remaining rows =

      A             B          C         
4     Item5         40         3
5     Item6          1         12
```

Unfortunaltely I get an error:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in cmp_method(self, other)
    103         if isinstance(other, (np.ndarray, Index, ABCSeries, ExtensionArray)):
    104             if other.ndim > 0 and len(self) != len(other):
--> 105                 raise ValueError("Lengths must match to compare")
    106 
    107         if is_object_dtype(self) and isinstance(other, ABCCategorical):

ValueError: Lengths must match to compare
```

I tried to resolve this problem several ways already. How do I have to approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reverse the column `C` then use [`Series.ne`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html) + [`Series.cummin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cummin.html) to create a boolean mask `m`, then use this mask to filter the rows in datframe:

```
m = df.loc[::-1, 'C'].ne(0).cummin()[::-1]
df1 = df[m]
```

**Details:**

```
print(m)
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4     True
5     True
Name: C, dtype: bool

print(df1)
       A   B   C
4  Item5  40   3
5  Item6   1  12
```

Comment: This  was a very elegant way to solive it! 
I am pretty new to pandas and was not aware of boolean masks. I am sure I will be able to use them for other problems as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A':['tem1','item2','item3','item4','item5','item6'],
    'B':[20,84,93,50,40,1],
'C':[5,0,1,0,3,12],

                   })

print(df)
       A   B   C
0   tem1  20   5
1  item2  84   0
2  item3  93   1
3  item4  50   0
4  item5  40   3
5  item6   1  12
df['check'] = df['C'].astype(str).str.extract('(^0$)')
df['check']=df['check'].bfill()
df=df[df.check.isna()]
del df['check']
print(df)
       A   B   C
4  item5  40   3
5  item6   1  12
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. 
Can you confirm If understood your solution? 
You turn C into string typ and extract the "0"s. You mark the missing values with bfill(). Filter for missing values and then delete rows which don't have missing values.